# Eclipse validation error with fontawesome-webfont.svg

Tags: eclipse, font-awesome

The Eclipse IDE validators complain about fontawesome-webfont.svg - which is part of the project http://fortawesome.github.io/

> The content of element type "font-face" is incomplete, it must match "((font-face-src,(desc|title|metadata)*)|((desc|title|metadata)+,font-face-src,((desc|title|metadata))*?))".

(EDIT: clarifying question)

1. Is the XML schema really being violated?
2. Is there an error in fontawesome-webfont.svg?  How could you fix fontawesome-webfont.svg?
3. Is there an issue with with the Eclipse validator?

---

fontawesome-webfont.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<metadata></metadata>
<defs>
<font id="fontawesomeregular" horiz-adv-x="1536" >
<font-face units-per-em="1792" ascent="1536" descent="-256" />
<missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="448" />
<glyph unicode=" "  horiz-adv-x="448" />

 ...

<glyph unicode="&#xf500;" horiz-adv-x="1792" />
</font>
</defs></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the validator telling you your file is invalid.  The message means that the contents of your font-face element have to match the sequence it relates.  It can not be EMPTY.  Try letting Eclipse generate a new XML file from the same DTD and you'll see what it needs to look like.

Comment: thanks - it is not my file in particular, it is from the font-awesome project: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/fc72d6388997a2ac14ce9335567fe0f3b4120123/src/assets/font-awesome/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg

Comment: the question is still open though - which is wrong, the DTD definition or font-awesome?  http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem related with the validator I guess, since the definition is right, if you check the definition of [defs Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#DefsElement) it allows an f[ont element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html#FontElement).

Also from mozilla sources:

**Permitted content:**

Any number of the following elements, in any order:

- Animation elements
- Descriptive elements
- Shape elements
- Structural elements
- Gradient elements

and

```
<a>, <altglyphdef>, <clippath>, <color-profile>, <cursor>, <filter>, <font>, <font-face>, <foreignobject>, <image>, <marker>, <mask>, <pattern>, <script>, <style>, <switch>, <text>, <view>
```

> Normative document    SVG 1.1 (2nd Edition)

So you can add to ignore in eclipse validator, please check this topic: [How to exclude specific folders or files from validation in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2272237/1006863)