# Scaffolding a new Angular app with Yeoman and Bower causes Eclipse out of memory

Tags: eclipse, angularjs, scaffolding, bower

I've just started with Yoeman, Bower and Grunt, and on two separate projects I've used Yoeman and Bower to scaffold an Angular application.

Eclipse (STS 3.4.0) both times immediately huffed and puffed and ran out of memory.
This is strange to say the least, because Eclipse has a lot of memory available.

I thought at first that I might exclude that massive 'node_modules' folder from validation, but I've already excluded all javascript files from any validation.

Has anybody got any clue why Eclipse dies on me when I use Bower?

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this by excluding the top Grunt node-modules folder from javascript validation.
A bit odd, because I had already disabled javascript validation for the project.

In Eclipse open the Preferences for the project with the problem, then click on 'Validation' in the left-hand column.

Then on the right-hand side click on 'settings' for Client-side javascript.
Then you add an Exclude Group, adding a rule for the folder you want to exclude.

This finally solved my problem.

---

Actually it was not a definitive solution. When I opened a new **node** project I got the same problem and my solution above was not effective.

The best solution is the last answer here, which I used to exclude the node_modules folder:
[How to exclude specific folders or files from validation in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272237/how-to-exclude-specific-folders-or-files-from-validation-in-eclipse)