# How to skip Specific file types validation from eclipse ( STS ) workspace validation

Tags: java, eclipse, validation

In my project there are many files (example ,*.cgm ,*.png etc)
Which are getting validated when i try to build the project or run Junit test case.

It takes lots of time to validate these files .As below message i can see 
[image]

i seach and went through this post 
[How to exclude specific folders or files from validation in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272237/how-to-exclude-specific-folders-or-files-from-validation-in-eclipse)

But it dont give a option to exclude CGM and PNG files

How can we exclude them from the validation.

I think it may be a checkstype validation.

Thanks

Comment: Eclipse doesn't validate png files. What should be invalid about them?

Comment: I can see the message when build is started or junit its launched 
"eclipse scoped incremental build before launch " and its is checking all the files including CGM ,PNG etc .

I think checking and validation is same no ? I am using 
STS - Version: 3.4.0.RELEASE