# How can I turn off javascript validation (including tern / lint / jshint) for certain folders (such as node_modules) in eclipse?

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, tern

I already went into project properties > JavaScript > Include Path > Source and excluded my node_modules directory.  But, when I run validation on the project it still tries to validate all of the javascript files in that folder.

Comment: It's because tern.java doesn't support include/exclude path. I'm working on this issue https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/issues/292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because tern.java doesn't support include/exclude path.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you that you [install 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) which provides the capability to exclude/include folders. To do that, configure those folder with JSDT **JavaScript Include Path**.

Comment: Hello Angelo.  I added that 1.0.0 snapshot and i don't see where I can exclude folders from validation.  Could you tell me where to go?

Comment: Your project must have JSDT Javascript Nature after that you go at JSDT JavaScript Include Path of project properties.

Answer (score 0):

I was also annoyed by all sorts of validation errors (json, html, xml...) in the *node_modules* directory. I didn't had at least javascript validation errors because I added only */src/main/javascript* to the JS build path.

For the other errors details are here: [How to exclude specific folders or files from validation in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272237/how-to-exclude-specific-folders-or-files-from-validation-in-eclipse), in particular check-out the comment from Jonatan Cloutier.